# How can I read System.Drawing.Bitmaps from a video file using FFMpegCore?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, bitmap

I am using https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore to write System.Drawing.Bitmaps to a video file and to read them back as bitmaps.

Based on the examples I was able to implement the first step as so:

```
public static void WriteToH264(System.Drawing.Bitmap[] bitmaps, string fileName)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)!);

    WriteToH264(
        bitmaps.Select(bitmap => new BitmapVideoFrameWrapper(bitmap)),  
        4,            
        fileName);
}

private static void WriteToH264(IEnumerable<IVideoFrame> bitmaps, int frameRate, string fileName)
{
    var videoFramesSource = new RawVideoPipeSource(bitmaps)
    {
        FrameRate = frameRate
    };
  
    FFMpegArguments
        .FromPipeInput(videoFramesSource)
        .OutputToFile(fileName, true, options => options
            .WithVideoCodec(VideoCodec.LibX264))
        .ProcessSynchronously();
}
```

For the second part I need to implement the following function using the same library:

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap[] ReadFromH264(string fileName)
```

But I have not find an samples of how to do this.

How should I implement this function?

Comment: Why not just read the github code and work out what you will get back from readH264?

Comment: Because there is no such function

Comment: Oh, you  want us to read the documentation and suggest what to use to achieve the same? I see in the readme of the project you can ask the library for a screenshot.. perhaps you could start there..

Comment: No, you don't need to read the documentation. I have already read it and did not find what I am looking for. Getting a screenshot is an unrelated function.